# When air is ionised, which component gases are actually ionised?

Tags: ionization-energy

Air is a mixture of O2, N2 etc. Which gases are ionised at STP, and is there a different level of ionisation for different gases?

Comment: Is not this a chemistry question? You could use the Chemistry SE for this one.

Comment: @KV18 Sounds like a physics assignment. So only a hint: think of the Boltzmann factor.

Comment: @Pieter - how air might be ionized May also come into play.

Comment: Everyone talks about air being ionised (such as an electrostatic ioniser) - I was idly wondering whether all the other gases were ionised at some point. I'm 71 - too old for a physics assignment!!

Answer (score 0):

The most common ionizations are of oxygen and nitrogen. Nitrogen ionizes first (at lower levels of energy input) and yields a deep blue color. Oxygen ionizes at a slightly higher energy level and adds a pinkish-white color to the plasma. Once the plasma heats up due to current flowing through it, it begins to emit a black-body spectrum and becomes white.

Comment: Are you sure about the order [Nitrogen 1st, then Oxygen], according to the Wikipedia Ionization_energies_of_the_elements_(data_page) Oxygen looses it's first electron at 1313.9 eV while Nitrogen holds on until 1402.3 eV

Comment: @user263399, in practice you see the N2 lines first and at higher voltages and power levels you get the O2 lines. I do not know why this is so, but in the test setup I built for my thesis work in 1977 this was consistently true.